# Parse std::uint types using stream manipulators in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, inputstream, manipulators

I am trying to parse a file using stream manipulators. However, as the operator>> overload for `std::uint8_t`, `std::uint16_t`, `std::uint32_t` from `<istreams>` is a formatted input function, it reads a string and if necessary converts it to a number. SO it would parse `23` to `23` and not the binary representation `00000010 00000011` to `515`.

You can do this using the `inputstream.read()` method with a `reinterpret_cast<>`:

`is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), sizeof(*data));`

Now my question - Is it possible to implement to overwrite the default behavior of the >> operator so I can read in such std:uint types using the >> operator? How would I implement it and how can I switch between the operators? And if it is not possible do you know a nice way to implement a stream manipulator to do the parsing?

Comment: So you have a text file and it contains binary representation of numbers, such as `0000001000000011`?

Comment: No, I have a file that contains data in binary representation, so if you open it you just see a strange blob of text. And i know that bytes i to j contain the file size, bytes k to l the data size, and so on. A normal binary file. And I am trying to extract the file header and the data.

Comment: Another thing to consider: Are you sure that the endianness on disk is the same as endianness in memory? Maybe look at the boost serialization library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ***not*** possible to change the `operator>>(std::istream&, uintN_t&)` overloads provided by the Standard Library.

You ***can*** add `operator>>(my_binary_stream&, uintN_t&)` overloads for your own stream type, and have them perform binary I/O.  (You can easily re-use the Standard Library streams objects in support of your custom binary stream, e.g. using their `.read()` and `.write()` operations.)

Answer (score 0):

Iostream `>>` and `<<` operators are intended for performing formatted i/o (think `printf` and `scanf`). There might be a way to override some part of the iostream hierarchy to do what you would like, but I would argue that it is not really expected that `>>` and `<<` would be used for binary i/o.

Binary i/o with iostreams is usually performed with the `read()` and `write()` methods, and requires you to open the file in binary mode:

```
 fstream f;
 f.open ("data.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

[Further examples here](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall00/binio.html).

You could write your own wrapper for `fstream` (or `FILE*`) and implement the operators that you need (just have them call the appropriate `read` and `write` methods).

As I noted in a comment above, be careful about the endian-ness of the data in the file. You may need to perform byte swapping on input/output as well.

For a full solution you could consider [`boost::serialization`, which takes a slightly different approach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).